# How to fix mail attachment received with 0 bytes using nodemailer in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, nodemailer

I am using node - 10.14.1 and nodemailer - 4.7.0

My problem is that when I send single row data from database in excel attachment , I am able to received mail with attachment but when I send multiple row data from database in excel as attachment, I receive attachment with 0 bytes and still showing downloading under attachments. I have images also in the file. Where as I am able to generate the entire excel file successfully but while attaching the file I have being failing .... I tried with sendgrid also but ran into same problem....

Can someone help me with my code, where I am going wrong.....

My code is-

```
exports.getExcelFile = (req, res, next) => {
   const excelFile = {};
   Order.findById(req.params.id).then(order => {
      excelFile.excelOffFile = "Off_" + order.factory + "_" + order._id + ".xls";
      excelFile.excelOffFilePath = path.join("data", "excel", excelFile.excelOffFile);
      excelFile.excelFactFile = "Fact_" + order.factory + "_" + order._id + ".xls";
      excelFile.excelFactFilePath = path.join("data", "excel", excelFile.excelFactFile);
      excelFile.excelBrFile = "Br_" + order.factory + "_" + order._id + ".xls";
      excelFile.excelBrFilePath = path.join("data", "excel", excelFile.excelBrFile);
      excelFile.excelSuFile = "Su_" + order.factory + "_" + order._id + ".xls";
      excelFile.excelSuFilePath = path.join("data", "excel", excelFile.excelSuFile);

      let workbookFinal = createExcelFile(order, "C", excelFile.excelOffFilePath);

      createExcelFile(order, "F", excelFile.excelFactFilePath);
      createExcelFile(order, "B", excelFile.excelBrFilePath);
      createExcelFile(order, "S", excelFile.excelSuFilePath);

      res.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/vnd.ms-excel");
      res.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename='" + excelFile.excelOffFile + "'");
      workbookFinal.xlsx.write(res).then(() => {
         res.end();
      });

      //-------- Sending Mail --------
      transporter.sendMail({
         from: defaultMailId,
         to: config.get("mail.defaultAdd"),
         subject: "Order with excel attachment send through software ",
         html: `<h1>
         The mail has been sent as trial through program for testing excel file attachement.
         </h1>
         <h3>
            file 1- ${url.format({ protocol: req.protocol, host: req.get("host"), pathname: "orders/genExcelFile/" + excelFile.excelOffFile })}</br>
            file 2- ${url.format({ protocol: req.protocol, host: req.get("host"), pathname: "orders/genExcelFile/" + excelFile.excelFactFile })}</br>
            file 3- ${url.format({ protocol: req.protocol, host: req.get("host"), pathname: "orders/genExcelFile/" + excelFile.excelBrFile })}</br>
            file 4- ${url.format({ protocol: req.protocol, host: req.get("host"), pathname: "orders/genExcelFile/" + excelFile.excelSuFile })}</br>
         </h3>
         `,
         attachments: [
            { 
               content: fs.readFileSync(excelFile.excelOffFilePath, { encoding: "base64" }),
               filename: excelFile.excelOffFile,
               type: "application/vnd.ms-excel"
            },
            {
               content: fs.readFileSync(excelFile.excelFactFilePath, { encoding: "base64" }),
               filename: excelFile.excelFactFile,
               type: "application/vnd.ms-excel"
            },
            {
               content: fs.readFileSync(excelFile.excelBrFilePath, { encoding: "base64" }),
               filename: excelFile.excelBrFile,
               type: "application/vnd.ms-excel"
            },
            {
               path: excelFile.excelSuFilePath,
            }
         ]
      }, (err, info) => {
         if (err) { return console.log(err); }
         console.log("message Send");
      });
   }).catch(err => console.log(err));
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. The excel file were not created successfully before mail was sent. So shifted the mail code out of the function in a new function and worked fine...